# Size of PNG header (with chunks and metadata)

Tags: java, png

I loaded PNG image to byte array and I need skip extras (header, chunks and metadata) and start reading bytes from bytes of main image.
But I don't know how to do that. Have all PNG images the same size of extras, or is it different for every image?
I found out, that header starts with 8-byte signature and than there are some chunks (IHDR..) and metadata, but I don't know the full size of these extras. 
Can somebody give me some advice about that please? If all PNG files have the same size of header what this size is or if haven't how can I skip this data and start read bytes from main image?

Thanks.

Comment: "I found out"?? The [official PNG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) tells you all there is to know. Find a Deflate implementation for your language of choice and you're set to go.

Comment: Thank you for comment and help, I don't found this specification before. But you can be more sympathetic, I really tryed to understand how it is and what size chunks in PNG have and just asked for little help..

Comment: This comment field is too small to copy the entire specification in. Read it -- then, for starters, write a program to list the chunks. It will be a useful learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to take a look at the PNG standard. After, the header, a PNG stream is divided into chunks. The chunks have a 4-byte length, 4-byte chunk type, then the data, and finally a CRC.

Use can use the chunk lengths to skip around in the stream.